# Using a second wifi router as a wireless bridge

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-bridge

I purchased a D-Link DGL-4500 to replace my aging WRT54G around a year ago, only to find it nowhere near as reliable. It's been collecting dust since.

I'm wondering if there is a way to use it as a wireless bridge so I can connect it to my home network and then use it's ethernet ports to provide network access to several devices.

Is this something that can be done? If not, are there devices meant for this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a link to its specifications? D-link's website was not very helpful today

Comment: http://www.retrevo.com/support/D-link-DGL-4500-Wireless-Routers-manual/id/4558ag701/t/2/ is the only thing I could find. Looks like D-Link orphaned a good number of links with a recent revision :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the admin section of the router's management software it is hard to tell. The irony is that you can definitely do it with the WRT54G using a custom firmware for the router such as DD-WRT http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index or Tomato http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato Lifehacker and Howtogeek have good tutorials on how to do this. I'm not sure if that would be an option given the D-Link is unreliable.

Comment: It doesn't look like it has an option. I instead decided to order a WRT54GL for $50 and use it with dd-wrt instead.

Answer (score 1):

The frimware DD-WRT is the best alternative to the wrt54g because this (dd-wrt) add to the router the capabilities as repeater, repeater-bridge, bridge, bridge-repeater router, and AP.
Many options to configure. Visist the web page: www.dd-wrt.com to verify what is the version number of you router, and install the correct version of dd-wrt.

Good luck!!

Srry for my bad english